# Xcode xccov command throws error "Failed to load coverage archive in scheme action"

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, code-coverage, xcodebuild

I have been using the following command on CI to generate a code coverage report for years:

```
xcrun xccov view --report --json path/to/App.xcresult > ./test_output/reports/xccov.json
```

In the last day (I'm not sure what changed), I have started getting this error:

```
2023-11-02 23:24:36.067 xccov[22876:146900] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEFoundation.IDEResultKitSerializationConverter
```

followed by:

```
Error: Error Domain=XCCovErrorDomain Code=0 "Failed to load coverage archive in scheme action 'Testing project App with scheme App' in result bundle" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load coverage archive in scheme action 'Testing project Handshake with scheme App' in result bundle, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001c70870 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Metadata.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/tmp/action.xccovarchive/Metadata.plist, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001c707b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}}}
```

I've searched all over for solutions but can't seem to nail down what the issue is. I tried the solution [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696270) to report coverage for all targets, but no luck there.

This happens in both **Xcode 14.3** and **Xcode 15**. My project is also using Test Plans. Has anyone run into this and know what the problem might be?

Comment: Hi @jshapy8, have you found a solution?

Comment: @wzso This was happening on CI and seemed to just go away eventually. We started clearing DerivedData before each build, that could have influenced it going away

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I also got rid of this error by upgrading to newer versions built with Xcode 15.

Comment: For anyone who is facing this issue, it might be worth trying what is mentioned here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734611